# C# - Getting the list or number of physical drives(not logical drives)

Tags: c#, winapi

I implemented the program to read and analyze physical disk bit-by-bit by accessing the path "\\.\PhysicalDrive0".

I want users to select the physical disk among the list of physical disks.

I know that I could read another physical disk if I change the last number of the path,
but I do not know how to get the physical disk list or the number of physical disks.

How could I get physical disk number lists?

Which function do I have to use?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use WMI, for example:

```
using System.Management;

List<String> result;
var query = new WqlObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive");
using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query))
{
    result = searcher.Get()
                     .OfType<ManagementObject>()
                     .Select(o => o.Properties["DeviceID"].Value.ToString())
                     .ToList();
}
```

This gives you a list of device IDs of physical drives in the system.

Comment: It outputs all same names of 4 hard disks.

Comment: I need the number of each physical disk.

Comment: I've updated my answer - though it was provided only as example code. Have a look at other properties available if that's still not what you're looking for.

Comment: If it works, mark his reply so that it can help others.

Comment: No, it does not work. On a PC with 2 system drives configured as RAID 1 and 8 data disks configured as RAID 10 this query returns 2 drives.